# Параметры вызова компонента bitrix:catalog.item

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите или дайте ссылку на документацию Битрикс с описанием компонента bitrix:catalog.item

Интересуют параметры вызова. Ни гугл ни яндекс ни поиск по документации ничего путного не показали. Вся информация - как поправить шаблон компонента. Но хочется понять именно параметры вызова.

Comment: В визуальном редакторе видны и названия и подсказки, если они есть.

Comment: И где по данной ссылке описание компонента bitrix:catalog.item? Ни одного слова про него. Это не "Элемент каталога детально (bitrix.catalog.element)".

Comment: и в визуальном редакторе этот компонент не присутствует. Он вызывается внутри компонента bitrix.catalog.section и возможно в некоторых других.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по коду компонента он не ждёт и не проверяет ничего кроме наличия **$params['RESULT']**, передаёт его в $this->arResult, и **$params['PARAMS']**.
Он просто проверяет их наличие и пересылает в шаблон.

Компонент обёртка-пустышка для выделения элемента списка в отдельный шаблон и применения его в разных компонентах.

Остальное делается в шаблоне.

```
class CatalogItemComponent extends CBitrixComponent
{
    public function onPrepareComponentParams($params)
    {
        if (!empty($params['RESULT']))
        {
            $this->arResult = $params['RESULT'];
            unset($params['RESULT']);
        }

        if (!empty($params['PARAMS']))
        {
            $params += $params['PARAMS'];
            unset($params['PARAMS']);
        }
        
        return $params;
    }

    public function executeComponent()
    {
        $this->includeComponentTemplate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Параметры вызова можно подсмотреть в catalog.section:

```
                        <div class="col-xs-12 product-item-small-card">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 product-item-big-card">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <?
                                        $item = reset($rowItems);
                                        $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                                            'bitrix:catalog.item',
                                            '',
                                            array(
                                                'RESULT' => array(
                                                    'ITEM' => $item,
                                                    'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$item['ID']],
                                                    'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
                                                    'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
                                                    'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
                                                    'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'N',
                                                    'SCALABLE' => 'N'
                                                ),
                                                'PARAMS' => $generalParams
                                                    + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$item['IBLOCK_ID']])
                                            ),
                                            $component,
                                            array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
                                        );
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Компонент catalog.item находится в bitrix / components / bitrix /